# How can I configure the methods allowed by CORS on my NestJs application?

Tags: node.js, cors, nestjs

Im doing an API with NestJS but I had an issue with the CORS, at first it didnt take the list of allowed domains and it allowed requests from any domain, so I implement this code to verify the origin and it works

```
options = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      myLogger.error(`Request not allowed by CORS`)
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  },
  methods: 'GET',
}

app.enableCors(options);
```

But this issue happens too with the methods inside the CORS, it allows to make any type of request and it ignores the configuration that I set. I tried to implement the same origin function on the method but it didnt work.

If anyone has a solution and/or experienced the same problem, I'd really appreciate it if you let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's allowing you to make any request because you are not making a [Preflight Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request); these types of requests are executed by the browser automatically.

Before every request, these execute an [`OPTION` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS#preflighted_requests_in_cors), if it meets the conditions you defined in your options, your request will be executed, otherwise, you will get a CORS error.

If you are using something like Postman or Insomnia to make a request of any type, it will always allow you, because it's a simple request.

In short, if you want to test if your configuration for `methods` is working, you only need to make a request of type `OPTION` and it should return, in the header `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, the list of methods you defined.
[image: Headers of an Option Request]

About the origin function, have in mind that you will need to send the header `Origin` in your request otherwise [it will be `undefined`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#:%7E:text=This%20function%20will%20be%20passed%20a%20string%20that%20is%20the%20origin%20(or%20undefined%20if%20the%20request%20has%20no%20origin)%2C).
And, if you don't want to allow the current origin you need to return false instead of throwing an error

```js
      myLogger.error(`Request not allowed by CORS`)
      callback(null, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be what you are looking for. This would be in your main.ts

```
  app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
//replace with proper error
    if (err.code !== 'CORERR') return next(err);
    if (whitelist.indexOf(req.originalUrl) !== -1) {
      next();
    } else {
      myLogger.error(`Request not allowed by CORS`)
      next(err);
    }
  });
```